# Nav won't open again

Tags: jquery, navigation

I managed to add a class for my navigation with jQuery, so it will be hidden, if someone clicks on a link in it.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#nav_mobile").click(function(){
        $("#nav_mobile").addClass("hidden");
    });
});
```

```css
#nav_mobile.hidden
  display: none
```

The problem is, it won't open again, if I click the burgermenu again... why? how?

Here's the thing on Codepen:

http://codepen.io/king_seba_one/pen/eBbNML

Comment: use toogleClass

Answer (score 0, accepted):

trigger the click of the button:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#nav_mobile").click(function(){
        $("#button").trigger("click");
    });
});
```

demo:http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GNPpRm

Comment: not working. Note that the `#nav_mobile` is not the button at the top right but the whole `nav` itself